# Определить количество переданных аргументов во внешнюю вызываемую функцию

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, split

Мне дана строка, в которой содержится определение некоторой функции, например, `f(x) := g(0, 1, x);`. Передаваемые в функции аргументы разделяются запятыми. Необходимо определить количество переданных аргументов во *внешнюю* вызываемую функцию функции `f`. Приведу несколько примеров:

1. Во внешнюю вызываемую функцию функции `f(x) := g(g(g(g(g(1, 1), 1, 1, 1, 1), 1, 1, 1)), 2, 3);` передано 3 аргумента, а именно `g(g(g(g(1, 1), 1, 1, 1, 1), 1, 1, 1))`, `2`, `3`.
2. Во внешнюю вызываемую функцию функции `f(x) := g();` не передано аргументов.
3. `f(x) := g(1);` - передан 1 аргумент (`1`).
4. `f(x) := g(g(1, 1), g(2), 3, g(g(4, 4), 4, 4, 4, 4), 5, g(6, 6, 6), g(7, g(7, 7), g(7, 7, 7), g(g(7, 7), 7)));` - передано 7 аргументов.
5. `f(x) := g(1, 2, g(3, 3, 3, 3, 3), g(4, 4));` - передано 4 аргумента.

Надеюсь, моя идея ясна. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как определить, сколько аргументов было передано во *внешнюю* вызываемую функцию. То есть, например, для функции `f(x) := h(g(i(k(x), 1), 1, 1), 2)` *внешней* вызываемой будет являться функция `h`, и ей соответственно было передано два аргумента в данном случае, а именно `g(i(k(x), 1), 1, 1)` и `2`. Другие примеры рассмотрены выше.

Я предполагаю, что данную задачу можно решить при помощи регулярных выражений, однако мне это сделать не удалось. Пытался следующим образом:

```
String f = "g(g(1, 1), g(2), 3, g(g(4, 4), 4, 4, 4, 4), 5, g(6, 6, 6), g(7, g(7, 7), g(7, 7, 7), g(g(7, 7), 7)))";
System.out.println(f.split("(\\(.*?\\))?,(\\(.*?\\))?").length);
```

то есть, я *отбрасывал* начало строки `f(x) :=` и точку с запятой в конце и работал конкретно с выражением, определяющим функцию. Приведённый программный код не всегда работает верно.

Comment: Обязательно регулярными выражениями? Каких типов бывают аргументы?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, далеко не принципиально регулярками. Аргументы такие, как я привел в примерах, функция либо целое число.

Comment: Тогда такой лайфхак. Надо просто посчитать количество запятых после нужной скобки. Когда попадаем на "(" увеличиваем счетчик на 1, если ")" уменьшаем. То есть, если значение счетчика больше 1, то мы во внутренней функции и считать запятые не надо, если равно 1 - то мы в нужной области и запятую нужно посчитать. КОличество аргументов = количество запятых +1

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, отличная идея, как раз недавно до этого додумался. Если нет других вариантов без написания этого цикла с подсчётом скобочек, ну так и сделаю. Просто вдруг есть более крутой способ, чем этот, например, может регулярками как-то в одну строку.

Comment: Я определенно верю, что это возможно сделать регулярками, но как говорится "Если вы надумали решить проблему регулярным выражением, теперь у вас две проблемы"

Comment: Используйте предложенный лайфхак с помощью стека.

Comment: Регулярными выражениями эта задача не решается.

Comment: Можно проще без стека

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, решил свой вопрос таким образом: https://pastebin.com/ZrTUyBGJ. Если в ближайшее время не найдётся более оптимального решения (не обязательно с помощью регулярных выражений), то я засчитаю данный ответ и помечу вопрос решённым.